# Translate and scale animation issue

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

```
@keyframes my-animation {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 40%) scale(0);
    }
    10% {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scale(1);
   }
   100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
   }
}
```

I'm trying to make my element pop then move on the Y axis, but the above fails to work.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `transform` overidies any previous transform property

Answer (score 9):

Transform property gets overridden during your animation. So even though the keyframe at 0% says translate by 40% in Y-axis, the second frame at 10% nullifies it. There is a movement between 0% and 10% but that is almost invisible because the element is just then coming into view.

You need to retain the `translate(0, 40%)` till the time the element needs to remain translated by 40% in the Y-axis. In the below snippet, I have retained it at the translated position till `20%` of the animation duration and then from between `20%` to `100%` it goes back to the original position.

```css
@keyframes my-animation {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 40%) scale(0);
    }
    10% {
        transform: translate(0, 40%) scale(1.1);
    }
    20% {
        transform: translate(0, 40%) scale(1);
   }
   100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
   }
}
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  animation: my-animation 4s linear forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div>Some</div>
```