# CSS animation with keyframes and hover

Tags: css

I am making my first website and got stuck. On page load I have animation (elements come down to place) but i also have :hover scale in it. So animation now works, but when I hover it does not scale up. Result I am looking for is on page load elements come down and then when you hover on them they scale up.

```css
top-header h1 {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color:white;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 10px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    transition: transform, scale 2s;
    transform: translateY(-80px);
    animation: come-in 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

top-header h1:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

@keyframes come-in {
    to {transform: translateY(0);}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>Li-designs</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Ignas Levinskas is young designer and web developer.">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"?>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Raleway:200,400,600,800" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <header>
            <div class="overlay">
                <top-header>
                    <h1>Ignas Levinskas</h1>
                    <social-header>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Ignasbelenkacia" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color:white" aria-hidden="true"> </i></a></li>
                         <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/burn_them_with_fire/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="color:white" aria-hidden="true"> </i></a></li>
                         <li><a href="https://www.behance.net/li-designs" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-behance" style="color:white" aria-hidden="true">   </i></a></li>
                     </ul>
                    </social-header>
                </top-header>
                <cover-content>
                    <h1>Welcome</h1>
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Ignas Levinskas designs logo">
                </cover-content>
            </div>
        </header>
    <main>
            
    </main>
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: write transform together [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551907/translate-and-scale-animation-issue)

Comment: @TimothyLee Scale animation should start after hovering. it's strange i think transition an animation property wont work together . if you delete your animation you can have scaled transition. the problem is how to use animation and transition on same property at same time

Comment: @AMH yea this is real issue. Seems that put transition and animation on same property cause conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You've put the rules in the wrong classes.

I've rearranged them like this:

```
top-header h1 {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color:white;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 10px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    animation: come-in 2s;
}

top-header h1:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transition: scale 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes come-in {
    from {transform: translateY(-80px);}
    to {transform: translateY(0);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any property used in element:hover should be present in element as well so that it can when hovered that property will be changed.

Here is your final working CSS.

```
top-header h1 {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color:white;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 10px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    animation: come-in 2s;
}

top-header h1:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
    transform-origin: top left;
}

@keyframes come-in {
  from { transform: translateY(-80px) scale(1);}
    to {transform: translateY(0) scale(1);}
}
```

and working example at codepen https://codepen.io/fearless23/pen/QgRMgb

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AMH you can add animation as well to hover styles https://codepen.io/fearless23/pen/awrLNR

Comment: I added transition to top-header h1, works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
top-header h1 {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;<---------------Remove
    transform: translateY(-80px);<---------------Remove
    //more code
}

@keyframes come-in {
   from { transform: translateY(-80px);} <------------Added
   to {transform: translateY(0);}
}
```

```css
top-header h1 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color:red;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: 10px 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  transition: transform, scale 2s;
  animation: come-in 2s;
}

top-header h1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

@keyframes come-in {
  from {transform: translateY(-80px);}
  to {transform: translateY(0);}
}

top-header h1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  padding-left: 100px;
}

@keyframes come-in {
  from { transform: translateY(-80px);}
  to {transform: translateY(0);}
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="overlay">
    <top-header class="x">
      <h1>Ignas Levinskas</h1>
      <social-header>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Ignasbelenkacia" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color:white" aria-hidden="true"> </i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/burn_them_with_fire/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="color:white" aria-hidden="true"> </i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.behance.net/li-designs" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-behance" style="color:white" aria-hidden="true">   </i></a></li>
      </ul>
      </social-header>
    </top-header>
  <cover-content>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Ignas Levinskas designs logo">
   </cover-content>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
</main>
```